# How to resize images to fit all content on minimal canvas?

Tags: bash, imagemagick

I'm trying to **quickly check for differences** between separate iterations of a [web site](https://www.your-loop.com/) **using ImageMagick's `compare`.** But it refuses to compare images of **different size**, and doesn't seem to have an option for simply emulating an infinite canvas anchored at a corner. `-subimage-search` is not what I want for several reasons:

- I don't know which image will be the bigger one (and I suspect it doesn't support images A and B where A is the tallest and B is the widest)
- I simply want to anchor the images at the same corner. Searching for the best match is likely to take *much* longer, and isn't going to give a better result (for this purpose).

The current solution works, but feels inefficient and cludgy:

```
max_width_1="$(identify -ping -format "%w" 1.png)"
max_width_2="$(identify -ping -format "%w" 2.png)"
max_width="$((max_width_1>max_width_2?max_width_1:max_width_2))"
max_height_1="$(identify -ping -format "%h" 1.png)"
max_height_2="$(identify -ping -format "%h" 2.png)"
max_height="$((max_height_1>max_height_2?max_height_1:max_height_2))"
convert -extent "${max_width}x${max_height}" -background transparent 1.png 1.png
convert -extent "${max_width}x${max_height}" -background transparent 2.png 2.png
```

Comment: Would it work if you just resized all images to a specific size and then compared?

Comment: @terdon We want to avoid using a giant size which may or may not be larger than the largest image ever produced.

Answer (score -1):

Variables abbreviated for visual clarity of code only, there's no need to change the *actual* longer (and maintainer friendlier) variable names.

The functional code can be reduced by using one instance of `identify` rather than four, using `read` to load the variables, (with an inefficient use of `xargs` to save a line of code), plus several `bash`isms:

```
read mw1 mh1 mw2 mh2 <<< $(identify -ping -format "%w %h " [12].png)
mw="$((mw1>mw2?mw1:mw2))"
mh="$((mh1>mh2?mh1:mh2))"
echo {1,1,2,2}.png | xargs -n 2 convert -extent "${mw}x${mh}" -background transparent
```

Or maybe it's cleaner to use arrays instead of vars:

```
read w[1] h[1] w[2] h[2] <<< $(identify -ping -format "%w %h " [12].png)
w[0]="$((w[1]>w[2]?w[1]:w[2]))"
h[0]="$((h[1]>h[2]?h[1]:h[2]))"
echo {1,1,2,2}.png | 
    xargs -n 2 convert -extent "${w[0]}x${h[0]}" -background transparent
```

Comment: This is IMO not an improvement. Shortening the variable names *reduces* the readability (and therefore maintainability), and these are still fundamentally very much the same approach.

Comment: @l0b0, Sorry for the confusion -- really I hadn't intended to recommend that *you* change any actual variable names.  The goal is rather to make the code fit more neatly on the web page window, rather than obliging users to scroll left & right.  As for the approach, perhaps a loop would be simpler...